# Why i can't split Each number on a separate line?

Tags: python, task

For Python task called like this:

**Write a program that reads three integers and displays their sum and multiply on the screen.
Each number is written on a separate line.**

I wrote like this

```
def sum(a, b, c,):
    return (a + b + c)
    return (a * b * c)

a = int(input('Enter 1st number: '))
b = int(input('Enter 2nd number: '))
c = int(input('Enter 3rd number: '))

print(f' sum of the numbers is equal to: {sum(a, b, c)}')
print(f' multiplication of numbers is equal to: {int(a * b * c)}')
```

in principle, it works correctly, but it does not take that line that I set at the beginning:

```
return (a + b + c)
return (a * b * c)
```

i even tried like this

```
def sum(a, b, c,):
    return (a + b + c), (a * b * c)
a = int(input('Enter 1st number: '))
b = int(input('Enter 2nd number: '))
c = int(input('Enter 3rd number: '))

print(f' sum of the numbers is equal to: {sum(a, b, c)}')
print(f' multiplication of numbers is equal to: {int(a * b * c)}')
```

Question:
How can I show separately on each line which command I should call?
it should be an whole number, not a string.
Perhaps need to write a program for entering numbers in a different way?

that's what results in

1. Enter 1st number: 5
2. Enter 2nd number: 5
3. Enter 3rd number: 5

**Me for second option given like this**

```
sum of the numbers is equal to: 15,125
multiplication of numbers is equal to: 125
```

**But i expect this**

```
sum of the numbers is equal to: 15,
multiplication of numbers is equal to: 125
```

Comment: your second code is the correct one, but it need to be modified so you got your expected values, once you call the function sum() it will return two values summation, and multiplications.
you can save their values as the following: sum_val, mul_val = sum(a,b,c) 
and when you want to print the value use sum_val and mul_val

Comment: @HammamAboJamous bad advice, don't do multiplications in a function called `sum`

Comment: your second code returns a tuple of 2 numbers, but you print them as one unit (the tuple), not likely you want the `,` in your expected output

Comment: *sum()* is a built-in function. Don't override it

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `return` statement is to **Give the result and End the function**. Meaning: When there is a return command, the return command will be executed and and the function gets completed. (i.e) the next line after `return` command will not be executed. So the program will stop with the first `return` command and the second `return` command will not be executed. So, this is how you can do:

```
def calc(a, b, c):
    add = a + b + c
    product = a*b*c
    result = f'''
sum of the numbers is equal to:{add},
multiplication of numbers is equal to:{product}
'''
    return result

r = calc(3,4,5)
print(r)

'''
output:
sum of the numbers is equal to:12,
multiplication of numbers is equal to:60
'''
```

Comment: don't do output in a calculation function

Comment: `Give the result and End the Program` is **NOT** the semantic of `return`

Comment: But why? What way is the pythonic one?

Comment: @rioV8, Kindly understand. The purpose of mentioning so, is to make a beginner understand. From his question I understood that the OP thinks that if 2 return statement is there, which will return 2 values. According to me, Rather using the proper definitions and technical terms, It's more important for  the OP to understand the concept. For the sake of this, we can compromise in technical terms and definitions.

Comment: @EsatBecco, The OP didn't mention that he/she wants in pythonic way.  Considering the OP's proficiency in python, I had to simplify.

Comment: `return` does not end the program, your statement is incorrect, and teaching beginners incorrect stuff is really bad

Comment: Rather than **End the Program**, [the return() statement, like in other programming languages ends the function call and returns the result to the caller](https://flexiple.com/python/return-in-python)

Comment: @rioV8 We all know that a tuple can also be written  without parentheses. So when the return statement returns multiple values separated by comma, It is as same as returning a tuple. i.e the program returns a tuple and ends.  The individual value can be accessed with `function_name()[index]`

Comment: @DarrylG, Thank you. Changed 'program' into 'function' now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to write your own function to calculate the sum and product because that functionality is available in the standard Python library.

Thus you could just do this:

```
from math import prod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))
            b = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))
            c = int(input("Enter 3rd number: "))
            v = a, b, c
            print(f"Sum of numbers is equal to: {sum(v)}")
            print(f"Product of numbers is equal to: {prod(v)}")
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
```